# Would a Zoan Devil Fruit that would turn someone into a fish person be affected by seawater?

Tags: one-piece

In the *One Piece* universe, Zoan Devil fruits give people animal-like abilities. Now granted, there are *already* amphibious mere-folk in this manga, but that's not to say there *isn't* (or at least, I have not yet seen) any Devil fruit that can give someone fish-like abilities.

If that's the case, would a Zoan fish Devil Fruit (say, a Fin Fin-fruit) that gave someone adapted aquatic abilities *still be bound* by the seawater weakness?

There are instances where this rule has been somewhat circumvented.... for instance, Brook can run *on* sea water without any ill effects, and his immortality means he can't drown.... however, it's uncertain if he were to *sink* into sea water if that same immortality would be negated and he would thus die permanently. It stands to reason, though, that if a person is a "fish person" then swimming in sea water would be a natural consequence.

Are there any instances of this occurring, or can anyone elaborate if this may not be the case, i.e., even given a new "fish-like" body, they would *still* be subject to the sea water-weakness rule?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at [this answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/25761/41946) on Anime & Manga, it points out this panel:

[image: "I'm a fishman, but I can't swim... It's because of the devilish power I received along with the 'Mato-Mato' curse!!"]

Vander Decken IX explains that he, a fishman, cannot swim. However, as the answer notes, he could still breathe outside of the air bubble when (spoilers for the Fish-Man Island arc)

> it was removed from his ship.

Thus, they extrapolate that **a human transformed by a fish Zoan fruit would still be affected by seawater, just like a fishman with a Devil Fruit. They could not swim, but would still be able to breathe.**